# When I am testing with JUnit how do I declare the Spring property place holder?

Tags: java, spring

This is how I declared the Spring property place holder for my application:

```
<context:property-placeholderlocation="classpath:config/base.properties,classpath:config/${target_env}.properties/>
```

When I deploy my application to the Tomcat webserver I give the target environment as argument

```
 -Dtarget_env=dev.
```

But when I am writing JUnit test cases how do I set the target environment value ?

Comment: You can set it also as parameter in your launcher

Comment: @Jens :  I didn't get .. Could you please explain more.. i tried giving as argument to my junit test . But it didn't worked.

Comment: If you are using eclipse you can use "Run" --> "Run Configurations" --> "Arguments" and there you can add it as an JVM Argument

Comment: @Jens : Yes i tried the same way but it didn't worked for me..

Comment: @jens : It's NOT working as u said. I get the below same error after passing as JVM argument. WARN PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Could not load properties from class path resource [config/${target_env.properties]: class path resource [config/${target_env}.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: have you set it including "-D"

Comment: I got it . In eclipse : Run as ->   "Run Configurations" -> Environment -> Create new - ( variable =target_env, Value =dev )

Comment: @Jens : It's working as i mentioned above . we need create Environment as above

Comment: Spelling, grammar, cleanup

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this . We need to create environment variabel as below in eclipse :

In eclipse : Run as -> "Run Configurations" -> Environment -> Create new - ( variable =target_env, Value =dev )